# error: expected `;' before ‘T’

Tags: c++, class

I know that this may be asked before, but unfortunately I couldn't debug the error.

I wrote a class for time:

```
class time
{
public:
    time(); //constructor
    void setTime (int, int, int); //set time
    void dispTime();  //print time
private:
    int hour, minute, second;
};
```

then I implement the function members:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
time :: time()
{
    hour = 12;
    minute = 0;
    second = 0;
}
//**********
void time::setTime(int h, int m, int s)
{
    hour = (h >= 0 && h < 12) ? h : 0;
    minute = (m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0;
    second = (s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0;
}
//**********
void time::dispTime()
{
    std::cout << ((hour == 0 || hour == 12) ? 12 : hour % 12)
              << " : " << (minute < 10 ? "0" : "") << minute
              << " : " << (second < 10 ? "0" : "") << second
              << (hour < 12 ? " AM" : " PM");
}
```

and finally below is the body main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
using namespace std;
//**********
int main()
{
    time T;
    cout << "The initial standard time is: ";
    T.dispTime();
    T.setTime(13, 27, 36);
    cout << "\nStandard time after set-time is: ";
    T.dispTime();
    T.setTime(99,83,12); //attemp to have a invalid time
    cout << "\nStandard time is invalid and standard time is: ";
    T.dispTime();
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}
```

when I compile it with g++:

4-5-class-time.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

4-5-class-time.cpp:8: error: expected `;' before ‘T’

4-5-class-time.cpp:10: error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does time.cpp (where you implemented the members) compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the name of your class `time` is a reserved word and cannot be used.  If you change it to `mytime`, like I did [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3FdDkh%246), you'll find it works as expected.

I'm going to have to find out *why* `time` is a reserved word or what's going on.

Apparently your class name conflicts with a global `::time` struct, which would make sense as to why it isn't accepted by the compiler.

If you really want to use a `time` class you should create your own namespace and put it in there.

`namespace tony { class time {}; } int main() { tony::time t; }` This should remove the name conflict.

Comment: A minimum example of this strange issue can be seen [here](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6c51d05873cd2f7d5f51cf98c451ffc9)

Comment: Thats *awesome*. At least clang is nice enough to inform me "Must use 'class time' to refer to type 'time' in this scope."

Comment: The combination of `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` pulls in thousands of names from the standard library. The `std::time()` function possibly being one of those.

Comment: @BoPersson I believe it is. prefixing the var-decl with `class time` seems to wire up correctly.

Comment: @user2090491 I just pasted your code verbatim fixing the time-decl and it compiles and runs. Care to elaborate on what "another error" is?

Comment: @user2090491 what error? You have to be **specific** around here, because *an error* is too vague.

Comment: I change it but there is another error:

/tmp/cc2DJz3F.o: In function `main':

4-5-class-time.cpp:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `mytime::mytime()'

4-5-class-time.cpp:(.text+0x1ad): undefined reference to `mytime::dispTime()'

4-5-class-time.cpp:(.text+0x1c5): undefined reference to `mytime::setTime(int, int, int)'

4-5-class-time.cpp:(.text+0x1dd): undefined reference to `mytime::dispTime()'

4-5-class-time.cpp:(.text+0x1f5): undefined reference to `mytime::setTime(int, int, int)' 
undefined reference to `mytime::dispTime()'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: That'll be the linker. You need link all the object files together to create the executable.

Comment: @user2090491 unrelated error. had you not had your last compiler error you would have had the one you have now. You're likely not compiling+linking all your source files correctly. It is not related to this question.

Comment: @TonyD yeah, I don't think the compiler is wrong either. the ambiguity is resolved in the std headers because everything in there is in the proper namespace. Outside them, with that using-clause, he (the OP) introduces the ambiguity and has to resolve it somehow. Luckily because the std header has it as a function, simply prepending `class ` will resolve the issue, but yuck, that doesn't exactly give me a warm fuzzy feeling about my code perhaps someday picking up the wrong def somewhere. (+1, btw)

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not sure the ambiguity comes from `using namespace std;`: See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to rename your 'class' files from time.h/time.cpp to mytime.h/mytime.cpp

There's a system include file called time.h and - depending on the include file search order configured for your compiler it's possible that the system file is being included in preference to your one. So the compiler never sees your Time class at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in time.cpp at line 22:

```
<< " : " << (seconde < 10 ? "0" : "") << second
```

Should be :

```
<< " : " << (second < 10 ? "0" : "") << second
```

Comment: It ran as expected on VC++ 2010.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <ctime>

namespace {
class time {};
}

int main()
{
    time();
}
```

Gives error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:5: error: reference to 'time' is ambiguous
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ctime:44:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/time.h:186:15: error: candidates are: time_t time(time_t*)
main.cpp:4:7: error:                 class {anonymous}::time
```

Getting rid of the anonymous namespace gets rid of the ambiguity. Strange:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:7:10: error: too few arguments to function 'time_t time(time_t*)'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ctime:44:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/time.h:186:15: note: declared here
```